# Extended inner-product on complexified spaces

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I am reading the book "The Index Formula for Dirac Operators: an Introduction” 
(via this link http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/biblioteca/pm/PM_10.pdf)

I am having trouble understanding the middle of pp.53 (I have the relevant screenshot below):

> [image]

Notice in the above image how the author says, *If the inner product ⟨ , ⟩ on V is bilinearly extended to V ⊗ C we see easily that*

[image]

However, since the extension of J is unitary with respect to this extended inner-product, the direct-sum decomposition into W and its conjugate is orthogonal. Therefore, we also have

[image]

Therefore, this extended bilinear-product is identically zero, and thus degenerate. I am wondering, how then can the statement in italics be true?
Perhaps it has to do with the fact that I am implicitly assuming that the extended inner-product is defined as

[image]

If so, what is the correct definition of the extended inner-product?

Comment: There is some confusion here. If the extension is _bilinear_ as the book says, then one does not get a complex inner product (which has to be sesquilinear). What you say about unitary and such only make sense for inner product spaces.

Comment: To add to the comment of @MarcvanLeeuwen , correct definition of the extended inner product is $\langle v\otimes z,u\otimes w\rangle=\langle v,u\rangle\cdot zw$.